# IndexError when Computing Maximum Distances in Brain-Strand Segmentation

Tags: python, index-error, mri

I need help with this project related to brain-strand segmentation. Im using the function bellow and console keeps sending:
`dist1[cont] = math.dist(p1, p2))`

IndexError: list index out of range.

Please help. Here's my code

```py
strands_selected = []
    dist1 = []
    dist2 =[]
    dist_max_d = []
    dist_max_i = []
    cont= 0
for i in strand_per_tractography:  # 100 000
        for k in strand_per_fascicle:  # 734 para el peor caso
            for p in points_of_interest:  # 3
                    p1 = tractography[i][p]
                    p2 = strand_per_fascicle[k][p]
                    p3 = strand_per_fascicle[k][p][::-1]
                    dist1[cont] = math.dist(p1, p2)
                    dist2[cont] = math.dist(p1, p3)
                    dist_max_d[cont] = max(dist1[cont], dist_max_d[cont])
                    dist_max_i[cont] = max(dist2[cont], dist_max_i[cont])
                    cont+=1
                    if cont == 2:
                     min_value = min( dist_max_d[p], dist_max_i[p])
                     if min_value < thresh:  # Verifica si la distancia es menor al umbral
                       strands_selected.append(tractography[i])
                       print (dist_max_d[cont])
                       cont = 0
```

I've tried changing dist_max_d and dist_max_i to this:

```
dist_max_d = [0] * len(points_of_interest)
dist_max_i = [0] * len(points_of_interest)
```

but then

```
dist1[cont] = math.dist(p1, p2)

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

`dist1`, `dist2`, `dist_max_d` and `dist_max_i` are all empty lists of length 0.

When you try to assign a value to `dist1[cont]`, that index does not exist, resulting in the IndexError.

You have two options:

1. Preallocate your lists to the required size. I actually couldn't determine this on examining the provided code, as my first assumption was on your for loop comments, giving a size of `100000 * 734 * 3 = 220_200_000`, but then I noticed you are resetting the `cont` variable to 0 under some conditions, and it wasn't clear if your indentation in the provided code is correct or not. As currently `cont` is only reset when `cont == 2 and min_value < thresh`

```
N = max_size_of_lists
dist1 = [None] * N
dist2 = [None] * N
dist_max_d = [0] * N # Use 0 due to the usage of max() when assigning values later
dist_max_i = [0] * N
```

2. Alternatively, instead assigning directly to a specific index, keep the lists empty to start, and use the `.append(value)` method.

```
    dist1.append(math.dist(p1, p2))
    dist2.append(math.dist(p1, p3))
```

Then instead of using `cont`, you just need to call the `.clear()` method on each list. However, there seem to be several possible issues with the `if` blocks at the end of the loop and I couldn't quite figure out what the intentions were, especially when you use `p` instead of `cont` to access `dist_max_d[p], dist_max_i[p]`